# Why when I send a post method with ajax, the data parameter is null?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api, axios

When i post to my api rest server the data is send null like the figure
[Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpI59.png)

And in the data base the value is saved like null
[data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYjuN.png)

**It´s the code from axios request**

```
const fileUploadHandler = () => {

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'text/json'
              }
          }
        axios.post("https://localhost:44387/api/Diagrama?nombre=ejemplo", {imageBase64}, config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
    }
```

**And it´s the code for controller in asp.net**

```
[HttpPost()]
    public String Post( [FromUri]string nombre, [FromBody]  string plano)
    {
        tbl_Diagrama diagrama = new tbl_Diagrama(nombre, plano);
        Console.WriteLine(plano);
        
        bdAplicacionServidor.diagramas.InsertOnSubmit(diagrama);
        bdAplicacionServidor.SubmitChanges();
        return plano;
    }
```

Comment: First and foremost, what is in the variable `imageBase64` at that time? It sure looks like it's undefined in the context of `fileUploadHandler`, where you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are looking for the parameter in the URL. But you there is no Url/Uri input. You did however, pass a query parameter. Here is the difference:

This is your full URL:

```
https://localhost:44387/api/Diagrama?nombre=ejempl
```

This is your URI:

```
https://localhost:44387/api/Diagrama
```

After the `?` is your query parameters:

```
?nombre=ejemplo
```

So your code is looking at `https://localhost:44387/api/Diagrama` and trying to find the `nombre` which you haven't specified in your Uri/Route. Instead you need to tell your code to get it from the query parameters like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public String Post([FromQuery] string nombre, [FromBody]  string plano)
```

If you did wanted to get it form Route/Uri then it would be the following:

```
[HttpPost("{nombre}")]
public String Post([FromRoute] string nombre, [FromBody]  string plano)
```

And the request will look as follow:

```
https://localhost:44387/api/Diagrama/ejempl
```